# Группировка данных по месяцам

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть массив данных: браузерные сессии разделенные по датам примерно так (в массиве данные за год):

| Браузер | Дата посещения |
| --- | --- |
| Firefox Mobile | 23.01.2020 |
| Opera | 13.01.2020 |
| Яндекс.Браузер | 14.01.2020 |
| Яндекс.Браузер | 31.01.2020 |
| Opera | 07.02.2020 |

Я уже третий день пытаюсь сгруппировать данные таким образом, чтобы у меня выводилось количество сессий на определенных браузерах за месяц.
Я понял, что можно посчитать общее количество сессий за месяц, например так:

```
df.groupby(df['Дата посещения'].dt.strftime('%B'))['Браузер'].count()
```

что даст результат:

|  | Дата посещения |
| --- | --- |
| February | 1 |
| January | 4 |

Но как при этом разбить эти значения по браузерам, внутри месяца и можно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вместо `count` возьмите `value_counts`:

```
res = df.groupby(df['Дата посещения'].dt.strftime('%B'))['Браузер'].value_counts()
print(res)
'''
Дата посещения  Браузер       
January         Яндекс.Браузер    2
                Firefox Mobile    1
                Opera             1
July            Opera             1
Name: Браузер, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так:

```
res = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date',freq='M'), "browser"])["date"].count()
```

res:

```
date        browser       
2020-01-31  Firefox Mobile    1
            Opera             1
            Яндекс.Браузер    2
2020-02-29  Opera             1
```